# Imfuse function in matlab not scaling while fusing two images

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, image-resizing

I am trying to fuse 2 CT and MRI images. But before i did that I tried to fuse 2 arbitrary images, registering them with mark and link registration method(mark points using cpselect). I tried to register both of the images with each other and then fuse them. But it seems that while fusing the images are not being resized to a same common size and then being fused. Instead the blending is happening on their original shape and size and hence they are not being blended appropriately. Why is this happening ? can someone suggest something ? I have tried to use different types of fusion approaches in the imfuse function but they have not been able to solve the issue. Is there an alternative function or an incorrect way in which i am using imfuse. Or perhaps something is being missed out ?

Here is the matlab code for what i have attempted :

```
CT_input=imread('C:\Semester 6\BTP\Spinal Cord Data\test\house1.png');
MR_base=imread('C:\Semester 6\BTP\Spinal Cord Data\test\house2.png');

figure, imshow(MR_base,[]);
   [input_points,base_points]=cpselect(CT_input,MR_base,'wait',true);

   geotype=cp2tform(input_points,base_points,'linear conformal');
   registered=imtransform(CT_input,geotype);
   registered2=imtransform(MR_base,geotype);
   figure, imshow(registered,[])
   figure, imshow(registered2,[])
```

---

Base images are the following ones:
1) Image 1
2) Image 2 ( slightly smaller and displaced image 1)
[image: House1, first image]

[image: House2 second image]

---

After registration:
1)Registered image 1
2)Registered image 2
[image: Image 1 Registered with respect to Image 2]

[image: Image 2 Registered with respect to Image 1]

---

Fused Image Obtained ( not a satisfactory level of fusion )
[image: Fused image]

---

Comment: you only need to `tformimage` one image w.r.t the other one. no need to move both of them...

Comment: I tried to do that but it doesnt really help me. I only registered the second image with the first one this time. now the fused image looks like this. http://imgur.com/yFUmEdN